# Is Hosea 13:14, quoted by Apostle Paul in 1 Corinthians 15:55, oddly mistranslated?

Tags: translation-philosophy, 1-corinthians, death, resurrection, hosea

Hosea 13:14 from the BSB translation:

> I will ransom them from the power of Sheol; I will redeem them from
> Death.
>
> **Where, O Death, are your *plagues*? Where, O Sheol, is your sting?** Compassion is hidden from My eyes.

1 Corinthians 15:55 from the BSB translation:

> “**Where, O Death, is your *victory*? Where, O Death, is your sting?**”

Paul clearly quotes Hosea 13:14 when describing the victory over death. However, Hosea 13:14 in modern translations render the passage differently then how Paul described it, replacing "is your victory" with "are your plagues", and "Sheol" (the Grave) is replaced with "Death" (thanatos).

This difference has created a controversy resulting in scholars being stumped and divided, thinking either that:

1. Paul was intentionally twisting the original passage in Hosea 13:14 to suit his message of victory, or
2. Paul was actually trying to quote the passage but made an unintentional mistranslation error, or that
3. Paul had a purer rendering of Hosea 13:14 that became corrupted later over time by Jewish translators, a rendering which we inherited up to the present.

I propose option 3, that Paul actually quoted Hosea 13:14 correctly and that the translation of Hosea 13:14 has become corrupted by translators. The context surrounding the current rendering of Hosea 13:14 does not fit a negative action of God denying compassion and calling upon Death to unleash plagues, but instead a merciful action of resurrection, redemption and deliverance. This is why Paul quoted Hosea 13:14, because it foreshadows the victory of Christ over Death and the Grave.

Could then this be the correct translation of Hosea 13:14?

> I will ransom them from the power of the Grave; I will redeem them
> from Death. Where, O Death, is your victory? Where, O Grave, is your
> sting? For sorrow will be removed from my eyes.

Any thoughts?

https://krharriman.substack.com/p/resurrection-in-the-ot-part-7

https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1178985.pdf

Comment: +1. Your proposal offers a pretty thought-provoking perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on variants, translations, and later Masoretic "recensions". Let's see which is closest.

Note that the Masoretes were traditionalist rabbis named after the Hebrew word *masorah*, which originated from the word “fetter,” and came to mean “tradition.” The Masoretic Text (MT) was the result of hundreds of “corrections” (their term) of the *Tanakh* in the 6th to the 10th centuries CE. These revisions, now called "recensions," corrected variant readings, and the variant Hebrew texts were destroyed. The oldest known Masoretic manuscript of the *Tanakh* is Aleppo Codex dated to 826 CE.

**Septuagint (literal Greek)**

> From out of *the* hand of Hades I shall rescue them; from out of death
> I will ransom them. Where is your punishment, O death? Where is your
> sting, O Hades? Consolation is hidden from my eyes. -Hosea 13:14 LXX
> (ABP)

**Dead Sea Scrolls**

Unfortunately, Hosea is significantly fragmented and chapter 13, verse 14 is completely missing.

**Syriac (Aramaic) Peshitta**

> From the hand of Sheol I shall redeem them, and from death I shall
> save them. Where is therefore your victory, death? Oh, where is your
> sting, Sheol? Comfort is hidden from my eyes. -Hosea 13:14

**Masoretic text (literal Hebrew)**

> From the power of Sheol, I will ransom them, from death I will redeem
> them. I will be your plagues, Death. I will be your destruction,
> Grave. Pity is hidden from My eyes. -Hosea 13:14

**Paul's letter to the Corinthians (in literal Greek, English word order)**

> Where *is* your sting, O death? Where *is* your victory, O Hades? -1
> Corinthans 15:55 (ABP)

The key words of comparison to 1 Corinthians 15:55 would be *sting*, *death*, *sheol or hades*, *punishment*, *grave*, *victory*, and *plagues*. Thus, it seems that Paul's quotation is closest to the Syriac Aramaic version.

Comment: Totally makes sense, and what an exciting revelation! Translators need to correct Hosea 13:14 to properly convey what is being said in the context, so that it reveals the mercy of God as the foreshadow of God's ultimate mercy in Christ – matching Paul's proper quote in 1 Corinthians 15:55.

Answer (score 1):

This matter was dealt with by Hebrew scholar Michael Eaton in his book about the prophetic book of Hosea.  He uses his own translation in his book but, of course, refers to other translations. The relevant  section is **29. The Defeat of Sheol** **(13:12-16)**   It is necessary to know what Hosea meant if we are to grasp what the apostle Paul meant when he quotes verse 14 in 1 Corinthians 15:55.  This commences with the sub-heading, *3. Hosea has a long-term vision of the day when death is abolished.* Here are the relevant bits:

> "Now [Hosea] turns to the day when the last enemy, death, will itself
> be destroyed. ... Eventually the creative event of Genesis 2:7 will be
> reversed and men and nations 'go back to the dust' (3:19). Death is
> removal from the presence of God, a change of location. Sheol is the
> place-name for death. It is death considered as being a place.
>
> Hosea looks for the nation of Israel to be spiritually 'resurrected'
> so as to come back to a happy relationship with God where it enjoys
> the life of God again.
>
> The Bible envisages a restoration of Israel. ***It was left to the
> apostle Paul to explain more.*** He tells us that 'Israel' was
> primarily a spiritual term for God's true people (Romans 9:6), that
> God's believing people in the earthly nation of Israel became an ever
> smaller 'remnant' as time went on (Romans 11:6), that Christian
> gentiles were grafted into that remnant so that they too became
> 'Israel' (Romans 11:11-24), and that one day there will be a spiritual
> awakening in 'national' Israel, and worldwide revival (Romans
> 11:25-32). Israel gets to be redeemed from Sheol.
>
> One further question demands thought. Was Hosea thinking of individual
> resurrection from the grave? That is how the pre-Christian Greek Old
> Testament took it.
>
> It is hard to see how one put any kind of limit to Hosea's prediction.
> Any thinking person would surely have to ask the question,  But is
> Sheol *completely* defeated or is Hosea only speaking of a restoration
> wholly within this life? Since the 'wages of sin' include physical
> death as well as damaged relationship to God, *deliverance* from Sheol
> must mean deliverance from physical death as well as deliverance from
> a damaged relationship wit God.
>
> The triumphant note in Hosea 13:14 confirms the point. **O death,
> where are your thorns? O Sheol, where is your sting?**
>
> How could Hosea use such triumphant language if he still thought Sheol
> would retain dying Israelite believers. Surely his view of the defeat
> of death must have been of the highest order for him to be able to use
> such a note of triumph.
>
> **So Paul had clear vision when he applied Hosea's words to the resurrection** (1 Corinthians 15:55) And **he could add a bit more and
> tell us what the thorns and sting actually are. 'The sting of death is
> sin'** (1 Corinthians 15:56) *Hosea,* Michael Eaton, pp.190 & 192-193, Christian Focus, 1996.

There are various Hebrew words that sometimes make translation into English difficult, but when Hebrew- and Greek-speaking Christians in the first century quote parts of the O.T., there only may seem to be a bit of a disjoint to us, but when we grasp what was in Hosea's mind, and then what Paul understood (given the further revelation of Christ's resurrection), we can see this is not a matter of mistranslation, but of further revelation that harmonises beautifully with what went before.

Answer (score 0):

Of the OP's options, option 2 is least likely as Paul possibly had much of the Bible memorized.  His great learning would also prevent such and "error".

Recall that the NT is divinely inspired and any such "errors" are very unlikely.  It is just as possible that there is a fourth option:

4. Paul was inspired by the Holy Spirit (2 Tim 3:16, 17, 2 Peter 1:19-21) to "adjust" the OT quote to better suit what he was teaching.

We see this kind of thing quite often in the the NT and Paul's writings.  Further recall that Paul does not explicitly attribute this to the Prophet Hosea and thus is bound to quote him verbatim.  That was part of the process of inspiration.

Lastly, Paul is more likely quoting the LXX which reads in Hos 13:14:

> I will deliver them out of the power of Hades, and will redeem them
> from death: where is thy penalty, O death? O Hades, where is thy
> sting? comfort is hidden from mine eyes.

Now, the LXX is far from uniform and several texts exist.  The form I quoted above is the most common in the 21st century AD.  However, Paul may have been using a version of the LXX now lost that said something closer to what he wrote.

In any case, we do not have enough information to finally settle the matter.  But it need not concern us if we believe that what Paul wrote was what he was inspired to write.

Comment: Can you give me an example of Paul "adjusting" passages from the old testament by altering them? I think Paul only directly quoted passages that were pointing to Christ in fullfillment.

Comment: @JoshuaB - Paul quotes the OT many dozens of times and only a very few of them are verbatim.  You will need to ask another question.

Comment: Can you give me one example aside from Hosea 13:14 that Paul does not quote verbatim?

Comment: @JoshuaB - how about Rom 11:8-10 quoting from Isa 29:10.  Indeed, most of Paul's and others' quotes from the OT are not verbatim.  Here are a few more: Matt 2:23; John 7:38, Eph 5:14, or even Matt 27:9.

Comment: @JoshuaB - what of Acts 15:15-18 vs Amos 9:11, 12.

Comment: +1 ... a much better approach than accusing Paul of intentionally twisting the meaning (option 1) or accusing the Jews of corrupting the original (option  3) . As @Dottard points out, several NT used OT scriptures in a new way, in light of Jesus' coming.  I prefer  simply accepting both Paul's and Hosea's version as authentic and inspired.  But option 2 isn't incompatible with option 4 IMO... God could have inspired Paul's misremembering Hosea.

Comment: @DanFefferman "God could have inspired Paul's misremembering Hosea"... I certainly don't think so!